# What's causing the background in a container to be cut off when window is resized smaller?

Tags: browser, css

My website has the typical container that is centered in the middle (very similar to Digg's V4 website actually).  The problem I'm having is that when resizing the window smaller than the container's width, anything with a background in the container appears to be cut off according to the window's width.  Digg's website actually has the same problem as mine too.  To illustrate, I've posted screenshots describing the issue.  The first screenshot has the window resized smaller than Digg's container width (notice the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom).

[image: Window has been resized smaller than Digg's container width]

Now the second screenshot shows what happens when we scroll to the right.  Notice that anything within the container with a background has been **cut off**!

[image: The backgrounds have been cut off]

To reproduce this, just go to Digg's website and resize the browser window to around 600px and scroll to the right.  Is this a fairly common problem with a fairly common solution? I tested this using Firefox 3.

Comment: I've always considered this a browser bug, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Mac: Firefox 3.6, Chrome 7beta, Safari 5. Sure it's not IE only?

Comment: FF 3.6.10 does this as well on Windows Vista. Definitely not IE only.

Comment: Reproduced on Ubuntu/Chrome 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set min-width on the problem div.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone points out the W3C spec justifying this behavior, I believe this is a common browser bug.